# mysqlclient 1.3.3 or newer is required; you have 0.7.11.None

Tags: python, mysql, django, pymysql, django-2.0

I'm using python version `3.6.3` and django version `2.0.1`.

I got the result below when I entered `py manage.py migrate` in cmd.

> (mysqlclient 1.3.3 or newer is required; you have 0.7.11.None)

I was trying to link a mysql database to my django project.

```
init.py codes:

import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

settings.py codes:

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite'),
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '8000',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see from your settings that you are using PyMySQL. Note that Django does not officially support PyMySQL.

Django recommends `mysqlclient` if you are using MySQL. As the error message says, Django 2.0 requires `mysqlclient` 1.3.3 or newer.

PyMySQL [has a shim](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/__init__.py#L106) for `MySQLdb` compatibility, but in 0.7.11 it pretends to be 1.2.6, which is too low for the Django 2.0.

```
# we include a doctored version_info here for MySQLdb compatibility
version_info = (1,2,6,"final",0)
```

The issue has been [fixed on the master branch](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/pull/623) so you won't get that error in the upcoming 0.8 release.

Finally, note that Django doesn't officially support PyMySQL, so you might hit issues if you use it. For example there's an issue with the [`BinaryField`](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/549).

Answer (score 1):

remove your code

```
#import pymysql
#pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

install python package "mysqlclient"

```
pip install mysqlclient
```